# How do you slow down the execution of a for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, timedelay

I am making a basic image slider (press the next/prev button and the picture changes). I am also trying to implement a very simple fade effect; to do this I have a for loop which changes the class of the image, cycling through classes that change the opacity. The code works fine and does what I want it to do, but the for loop executes so quickly that you don't notice the change in opacity. I have looked all over and everywhere people are mentioning setTimeout, but that only causes a delayed start of a function.. I just want to slow my for loop so you can visually notice each iteration.

```
function nextphoto(){

    for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++){
        photo.className = fade[x];
    }

    i++;
    if(i>19){
    i=0;
    }

    photo.src = image[i];

    for(var y = 4; y >= 0; y--){
        photo.className = fade[y];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a complicated way to do something simple, why don't you just animate the opacity using CSS transitions and toggling a single class on the outgoing and incoming divs? That way you only need a setTimeout on the incoming element's class change.

Comment: maybe `setInterval()` is the right way to operate delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be misunderstanding the concept of synchronous code execution. All of your code has to finish running before anything can be updated or "rendered" to the screen. So your for loop will run until it's done, then the screen will update, but it will of course only have the final view of the image to render.

You should either trigger a CSS transform, by dynamically adding a class to the element via javascript, or if you were desperate to do it all in code, had some reason not to use CSS, and do not want to write a custom per frame animation system, or use a library, then inside each iteration of the for loop, fire an asynchronous function that will update at a later and later time, outside of the current synchronous for loop code.

ie:

```
var aThing;
for(var i = 0; i < someNumber; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
    aThing.someValue = aThing.someValue * .9;
  }, 500 * i);
}
```

Comment: I was unaware of the synchronous code execution; thanks for the explanation this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using JQuery's animate() function to animate css values like opacity. Even better you could be using CSS animations.

What you're doing is NOT a good way to achieve your goal. If you really want it that way you should use setInterval or setTimeout.

Comment: Yes using Jquery or css transitions is probably the better idea, I was just wondering if I could do it using pure JavaScript - though it appears more trouble than necessary. Thanks!